# Backdrop map tiles missing in R Leaflet .png output

Tags: r, leaflet, png

I used `leaflet.extras::addBingMaps()` to pull in some Bing Maps tiles to visualise an area in China, and then tried to save the map to a .png file using `mapview::mapshot()` to include in my report:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(mapview)

leaflet() %>% 
  fitBounds(lng1 = 117.3, lat1 = 40.9, lng2 = 117.4, lat2 = 41.0) %>% 
  addBingTiles(
    apikey = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_API_KEY",
    imagerySet = "CanvasLight"
  ) %>%
  addScaleBar(position = "bottomleft") %>% 
  mapshot(
    file = "test.png",
    remove_controls = c("zoomControl", "layersControl", "homeButton")
  )
```

In the saved .png file I found missing tiles:

[image]

However, if not output as the .png file, the interactive leaflet map rendered correctly.

I wonder whether it was because `addBingTiles()` timed out, but did not find in its documentation how to extend the waiting time to render all tiles. As I am writing this question, I found some other people having similar problems but not in R. Therefore, I would really appreciate any experienced R user's help.

Comment: In the `mapshot` call try adding `delay = 5` to allow 5 seconds for the rendering of the map before taking the screenshot. Or increase even further depending on the internet connection. See `webshot::webshot` for the documentation of the `delay` argument.

Comment: Thanks so much @TimSalabim - it worked perfectly. I had a glance at the documentation of `mapshot()` hoping to find an argument like this, but did not notice that it also accepts arguments from `webshot()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TimSalabim, who brought my attention to that `mapview::mapshot()` also accepts the `delay` argument passed to `webshot::webshot()`. This would allow extra waiting time to render all the map elements before the screenshot is taken – problem solved!